# NS2: How to set queue-limit for a node

Tags: simulation, ns2

I'm trying to simulate this network with NS2:
[image]

and I have built the network like this

```
#Create six nodes
set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
set n3 [$ns node]
set n4 [$ns node]
set n5 [$ns node]

set recvr_delay1 [new RandomVariable/Uniform];
$recvr_delay1 set min_ 5ms
$recvr_delay1 set max_ 25ms

set recvr_delay2 [new RandomVariable/Uniform];
$recvr_delay2 set min_ 5ms
$recvr_delay2 set max_ 25ms

# TODO: make these delays random
#Create links between the nodes
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n2 100Mb 5ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 100Mb $recvr_delay1 DropTail

$ns duplex-link $n2 $n3 100Kb 1ms DropTail

$ns duplex-link $n3 $n4 100Mb 5ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n3 $n5 100Mb $recvr_delay2 DropTail
```

and I know that we can set queue-limit for links in NS2:

```
$ns queue-limit $n0 $n1 10
```

But the problem is I don't want to set queue-limit for links, I want to set queue limit for those two routers, is there a way to set queue-limit for a node instead of a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [NS Simulator for Beginners book](https://books.google.ae/books?id=waheAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=tcl%20queue%20limit&source=bl&ots=w8e7rKKNzs&sig=ACfU3U1Q6GR_KMW3ds4YGuX18dKGwQkt8g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtpI79hZjqAhUYSRUIHbkfDzIQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=tcl%20queue%20limit&f=false)

"In NS-2, an output queue of a node is implemented as a part of each link whose input is that node. The definition of the link then includes the way to handle overflow at that queue."

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: This answer is true, now the question is if there is a duplex link between two routers should we set the queue limit twice or once is enough for both ways?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add something to the accepted answer.
you can use two simplex links(same as a duplex link), and only assign queue limit to one of them.
for example suppose we want to make a duplex link between node R and node B:

```
set R [$ns node]
set B [$ns node]

$ns simplex-link $R $B 1Mb 100ms DropTail
$ns simplex-link $B $R 2Mb 100ms DropTail

$ns queue-limit $R $B 10
```

Now only node R will have queue limit of 10.